# selecting specific fields in a structure array based on the values of the field.

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I am new to MATLAB and would really appreciate your help. I have a structure "s" and inside "s" I have fields one of which is "t" for trials and inside "t" I have almost 20 other fields and they all have values written in 1xn matrices. I have almost 900 trials and want to select specific ones based on the values of the field A inside each trial (s.t.A). how can I do this? I am a bit lost that I cant even figure out what I should look for. thank you.

Comment: could you give a brief example of your question, with the input and result please. I assume you just want indexing which can be quite easily done by looking at your data. Assume S is 4 dimensions,You could try s(:,t,1,:) set t=1 and see what you get

Comment: its a <1x1 struct> "s" which contains a field named "t" that is <1x900 struct>. t has 900 cells and each cell contains all data under different field names for example "direction" which is a vector [a a a a ...] with variable lengths for each trial "t". the value of a is either 0 or 180. I want to group or select all the trials "t" that have the value 180 for direction. thank you so much

Comment: Ok I see, you can select cells using curly brackets {, the indexing should be just the same as in matrices.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what your variables actually are, and it matters a lot for how you can operate on them. For example, you may want to look into `structfun` for your problem - it allows you to apply a function to each field of a structure, but it must be scalar, e.g. `structfun(@(x) x==180,s.t)` would return the result of `==180` for each field of `t`.

If your struct isn't scalar, then you could try logical indexing, e.g. `[s.t([s.t.direction]==180)]` will return a struct where the condition `direction == 180` was true.

If you supply the actual variable you are working with then you'll probably get more helpful answers.

Comment: data look more like this:
DATA = struct('Direction',{[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,1,2],[2,2,2,2]},'Trial',{'correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct','correct'});
**this is just an example and i have other fields as well**
so for example I just want to work with the cells in my struct which have the Trial as 'correct' and I would like to store them in a separate struct along with their corresponding Direction for that cell. I am not sure if im clear or not I apologize for that.